# How to set up a feedback form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make a feedback form for a website. From what i have read i need a database and such. I was wondering if there is a way to do this without a database. I want the form to have a your name feild, a your e-mail field, and a your message field, i have tried lots of other feedback forms on the internet but none worked. I don't have a very good computer so i can't make a web server or a database all i have is the websites domain.  Any help will be greatly appreciated. I want the message to be sent to my Hotmail account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not have to complicate yourself. Just use google forms.
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?hl=en

**Create a form from your Drive:**

1. Click the red Create button, then Form.
2. In the form template that opens, you can add any questions you'd like. You can also organize your form by adding headers and dividing your form into several
   pages. Learn more about editing your form.
3. If you’d like those who
   complete your form to see a progress bar indicating how much of your
   form they’ve completed, check the box labeled “Show progress bar at
   the bottom of form pages.”

**Create a form from a Google spreadsheet:**

1. While working with a spreadsheet, click the Insert menu and select Form.
2. A message will display at the top of the page notifying you that a new form has been created.
3. Click Add questions here to begin editing your form, or Dismiss to get rid of this message and continue editing your spreadsheet. (Note: If you dismiss this message, you can edit your form at any time by selecting the Form menu and clicking Edit form.)
4. After creating a form from a Google spreadsheet, you’ll notice a new tab at the bottom of your spreadsheet labeled “Form responses.” As you might have guessed, this is where responses to your form will be added.

You can also send a mail to yourself when you get any responses.

Comment: Ok but how do i add this to my website